# Add another list of TOC in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I have a very big presentation on beamer so i should separate items of toc in two slides. How can i do this? For example i want first and second sections be on the one TOC slide and third on another.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{\LARGE{TOC}}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}

\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\stdsection}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
1

\section{test}
2

\section{test}
3

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define which sections the toc should display by using `\tableofcontents[sections=1-2]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{\LARGE{TOC}}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<1>{\tableofcontents[sections=1-2]}
\only<2>{\tableofcontents[sections=3]}
\end{frame}

\section{test1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{test2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{test3}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```